# if error == nil parse swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3, parse-server

I'm trying to check when I save an object to my parse serve if something goes wrong. But I have two options and I have three options and I don't know the difference. I have these three options (if error == nil, or if object != nil, or if error == nil and object != nil). Which one should I use. Thanks

Option #1

```
let user = PFUser.current()!
user.saveInBackground (block: { (success:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in
    if error == nil{
    }
)}
```

Option #2

```
let user = PFUser.current()!
user.saveInBackground (block: { (success:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in
    if object != nil{
    }
)}
```

Option #3

```
let user = PFUser.current()!
user.saveInBackground (block: { (success:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in
    if error == nil && object != nil{
    }
)}
```

Comment: Hint: ` (block: ` can be removed (together with the parentheses that should actually be last), as can the `-> Void` be removed and the the type annotations for the closure arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest and encourage you to use guard statement, which as made for such situations.

```
    //Always safely unwrap optional value:
    if let user = PFUser.current(){

    user.saveInBackground (block: { (success:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in

        guard success, error == nil else {
        //handle error somehow...(print or whatever...)
        return
         }
       //Continue here as everything is fine...

    )}
}
```

Comment: can I ask you something what if I have inside the block, (object, error). Can I still use the guard solution you have above. Please let me know so I can add a checkmark to one of the solutions above.

Comment: if the object is optional, you can unwrap it with guard too like this: 




`user.saveInBackground (block: { (success: AnyObject?, error:Error?) -> Void in


    guard let object = object, error == nil else {
    //handle error somehow...(print or whatever...)
    return
     }

    print(object)
    //Object is now unwrapped so do what you want.
   //Continue here as everything is fine...

)}
`

Comment: And sorry the Markdown seems to be broken in comments.. just copy paste the code from answer and make the indents/spaces

Answer (score 0):

Better to use different handlers for success and for failure:

```
func saveInBackground(success: () -> Void, failure: (Error?) -> Void) {
    /* do whatever you need */
    if saved {
        success()
    } else {
        failure(saveError)
    }
}

saveInBackground(success: {
    /* saving was succeed */
}, failure: { (error) in
    /* saving was failed */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There should never be an error when the save operation succeeds, as a general rule of thumb, it depends on the next steps of your implementation. None of the approach is invalid, i would still recommend that you check the ‘happy value’, object, succeed dtc... before checking the error